# How to Repeat Header in Datalist when Repeating Colums=2

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Requirement is to display the DataList as Below

```
Header1      Header2          Header1      Header2           

1            Value 1            3          Value 3                        

2            Value 2            4          Value 4
```

But I'm unable to repeat the header section of the data list.
My complete code stuff for datalist is

```
     <asp:DataList ID="datalstProfileCount" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        RepeatLayout="Table" ShowHeader="true" OnItemDataBound="datalstProfileCount_ItemDataBound">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#e1e1e0" style="border: solid 1px #e1e1e0;
                                font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; width: 400px">
                                <tr style="font-size: 13px; background: #ffedc2; border-bottom: 1px solid #eba602;
                                    border-left: 1px solid #d6d6d6; font-weight: 600; font-size: 13px; padding: 10px 8px;
                                    color: #c82124;">
                                    <td style="width: 80px; color: #c84241; text-align: center; padding: 6px">
                                        Name
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 100px; color: #c84241; text-align: center; padding: 6px">
                                       Total Count
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 100px; color: #c84241; text-align: center; padding: 6px">
                                        Active Members Count
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#e1e1e0" style="border: solid 1px #e1e1e0;
                                font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; width: 400px; margin: -1px">
                                <tr style="font-size: 12px; vertical-align: middle; color: #9d9d9c;">
                                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 80px; color: #333333; padding: 6px">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px; color: #333333; padding: 6px">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalCount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TotalCount") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px; color: #333333; padding: 6px">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblActiveMembersCount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ActiveMembersCount") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-top: 20px" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 14px">
                                        Total Count:
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblProfileCount" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="#C82124" Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 14px">
                                        Active Members Count:
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMemberCount" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="#C82124" Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
```

Please anyone of you help me.. And thank you in advance...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Header will never repeat itself, make the Header HTML as a part of Item Template. As per the .Net Controls implementation, Header is the Head of your list will only come once, then your Item Template which will be repeated based on the number of items present in your data source and then comes the footer..

Something like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalstProfileCount" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"   RepeatLayout="Table" ShowHeader="true" OnItemDataBound="datalstProfileCount_ItemDataBound">
          <HeaderTemplate>         
          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
                    //Header Section
                    //Data 
          </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

If you still have some confusion share your whole Data list with Header Section and Data section which you mentioned in the comment, i will provide you the updated code..

Updated Answer:

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalstProfileCount" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        RepeatLayout="Table" ShowHeader="true" OnItemDataBound="datalstProfileCount_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#e1e1e0" style="border: solid 1px #e1e1e0;
                font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; width: 400px; margin: -1px">
                <tr style="font-size: 13px; background: #ffedc2; border-bottom: 1px solid #eba602;
                    border-left: 1px solid #d6d6d6; font-weight: 600; font-size: 13px; padding: 10px 8px;
                    color: #c82124; visibility: hidden;" id="trHeader" runat="server">
                    <td style="width: 80px; color: #c84241; text-align: center; padding: 6px">
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 100px; color: #c84241; text-align: center; padding: 6px">
                        Total Count
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 100px; color: #c84241; text-align: center; padding: 6px">
                        Active Members Count
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="font-size: 12px; vertical-align: middle; color: #9d9d9c;">
                    <td style="text-align: left; color: #333333; padding: 6px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: #333333; padding: 6px">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalCount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TotalCount") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: #333333; padding: 6px">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblActiveMembersCount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ActiveMembersCount") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-top: 20px" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px">
                                    Total Count:
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-left: 10px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblProfileCount" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="#C82124" Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size: 14px">
                                    Active Members Count:
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-left: 10px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMemberCount" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="#C82124" Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

On Server Side add this code:

```
protected void datalstProfileCount_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if(e.Item.ItemIndex <=1)
        {
            var headerRow = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("trHeader");
            if(headerRow != null)
            {
                headerRow.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might need to do some changes in the styles but that can also be achieved.

Comment: If we give like that then the header will repeat for every row.

Comment: I just want to repeat the header only for two times with repeated columns 2. Got my point??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36431/discussion-between-vamsi-pamula-and-abhishek-jain)

Answer (score 0):

**Add 'If datalistName.Items.Count > 1' Code sample:**

```
    <HeaderTemplate>
          <table>
              <tr><td>Header1</td><td>Header2</td></tr>
                 <%If (data_list_name.Items.Count() > 1) {%>
                   <tr><td>Header1</td><td>Header2</td></tr>
                 <%}%>
          </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
```